# Why is my if clause are not working? How can fix variable types?

Tags: c++, arduino

I want to change parameters with udp sentences. I'm getting udp's but my if clause is not working. How can compere 2 variables?

I have changed variable types and/or if clause type (ex if ( strcmp ( UdpMsg , "relay01_off" ) == 0)  ).

Setup IF clause variable

```
String UdpMsg = "12345";...
```

Getting UDP Message

```
String UdpMsg ((char *)buffer);...
```

IF clause

```
if ( UdpMsg == "relay01_off" ) {
  digitalWrite(relay_pin, HIGH);
  Serial.print ("You!\n");
  }
```

I expected to see "you!" when i send UDP but it's not finding equals.

Full Code for info:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <cstring>  //For the string functions

const char* wifi_name = "SSID";          // Your Wifi network name here
const char* wifi_pass = "password";     // Your Wifi network password here
WiFiServer server(80);                      // Server will be at port 80

// IP address to send UDP data to.
const char *  udpAddress = "192.168.1.6";
int           udpPort = 4444;

//create UDP instance
WiFiUDP udp;

// relay PINi
int relay_pin = 15;

// UDP Mesajı gelen
String UdpMsg = "12345";

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  pinMode (relay_pin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.print ("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print (wifi_name);
  WiFi.begin (wifi_name, wifi_pass);     // Connecting to the wifi network

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) // Waiting for the response of wifi network
  {
    delay (500);
    Serial.print (".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Connection Successful");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());           // Getting the IP address
  Serial.println("Type the above IP address into browser search bar"); 
  server.begin();                           // Starting the server
  digitalWrite(relay_pin, LOW);           // switch i AC

  //This initializes udp and transfer buffer
  udp.begin(udpPort);
}

void loop() 
{
  uint8_t buffer[50] = "";
  //processing incoming packet, must be called before reading the buffer
  udp.parsePacket();
  //receive response from server, it will be HELLO WORLD
  if(udp.read(buffer, 50) > 0){
    Serial.print("Recevied UDP: ");
    Serial.println((char *)buffer);
    String UdpMsg ((char *)buffer);
  }

  //////// UDP IF leri ///////////
  if ( UdpMsg == "relay01_off" ) {        // Equal strings
    digitalWrite(relay_pin, HIGH);
    Serial.print ("You!\n");
  }

}
```

Comment: @JaMiT The definition of `String` is in Arduino C++ documentation: [String()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable assignments when using if statements in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56115200/variable-assignments-when-using-if-statements-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you construct a second `UdpMsg` variable in:

```
  if(udp.read(buffer, 50) > 0){
    Serial.print("Recevied UDP: ");
    Serial.println((char *)buffer);
    String UdpMsg ((char *)buffer); // <--- 2nd UdpMsg, released after 'if' clause
  }
```

While `UdpMsg` at this line:

```
if ( UdpMsg == "relay01_off" )
```

refers to the first one, the global, that keeps its initial value "12345".

Comment: Well as i understand that was NOT my problem. But you help me solve my problem. My IF clause WAS outside of "void loop() " so it was taking global value. When it was in the loop it worked. Thank you